# Is it valid <base href="/"> to be compatible with across all browser?

Tags: html

Is is valid to use `<base href="/">` in HTML? I can't find reference according this. [Official specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) refers this element as following:

> The base element allows authors to specify the document base URL for
>   the purposes of resolving relative URLs, and the name of the default
>   browsing context for the purposes of following hyperlinks. The element
>   does not represent any content beyond this information.

Nothing about using `/` as URL.

So is it valid to use `<base href="/">` ?

Comment: Why would it need to explicitly mention one particular URL as being valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `href` accepts valid URLs, and `/` is a valid URL

> The [`href`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-base-href) content attribute, if specified, must contain a [valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces).

For example, suppose the document in http://example.com/some/path contains this link:

```html
<a href="foo">Link</a>
```

It will point to http://example.com/some/foo. But if you add

```html
<base href="/" />
```

then it will point to http://example.com/foo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it supported by all browsers?